# Authorization to select option in drop-down

Tags: python, authorization, pyramid

I have a web tool in python-pyramid. On a page we have a drop down with 20 options. This page is visible to everyone who logs on the web tool. I had put authorization/restriction on options available to a user on this page.

My current design is a 2D matrix which tells for which user what options are available. I m  querying the matrix and displaying the options to user. Now I am thinking is it possible to use `pyramid.authorization` here?

My understanding is that we use `pyramid.authorization` when we have different pages, associated views (edit,view,create) for user (admin, normal user etc). Since I have only one page, `pyramid.authorization` can't be used.

Am I correct ? or if I can use `pyramid.authorization` in my design then how to use it?

Comment: i have never used pyramid, but i think if you embed pages into your main page than you could do it like that maybe?

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite clear what "2D matrix of options" is, but I'll assume you're talking about links to other pages (or forms submitting to other views), and you want to show/hide options depending on whether the user has permission to view the target page or to invoke the target form submit handler.

In this case, [pyramid.security.has_permission](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.0-branch/api/security.html#pyramid.security.has_permission) should solve your problem. Just protect your *target* views with appropriate permissions and use this function in your "home page" view to determine if the current user should be shown each particular menu item.